# AWS API Gateway with Lambda Authorizer

Tags: aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0, openapi, lambda-authorizer

I am trying to configure an API Gateway which takes a proxy parameter from the request path, and also a parameter from the Lambda authorizer return and put it in the header, so that it can be passed to my Elastic Beanstalk REST API running Spring Boot.

The proxy path is working as expected; and I see my Lambda function is returning the variable "x-api-auth" in the "context" map as per documentation.

The only piece not working is adding "x-api-auth" to the request header. :( Whenever I ran my Jenkins build to update the Cloudformation stack, I get this error:

```
Errors found during import: Unable to put integration on 'ANY' for resource at path '/sfdc/v1/feature-api/{proxy+}': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: $context.authorizer.x-api-auth] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException
```

It is super frustrating and I've double checked OpenAPI documentation to make sure my syntax is correct. Any help or tips would be most appreciated!

Here is the Cloudformation template I have:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Data API pipeline initial Cloudformation template

Mappings:
  EnvironmentMapping:
    alpha:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: XYZ
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
    beta:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: XYZ
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
    prod:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: ABC
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
Parameters:
  EnvironmentType:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedValues:
      - alpha
      - beta
      - prod

Conditions:
  UseProdCondition: !Equals [!Ref EnvironmentType, prod]

Resources:
  MyApiVpcLink:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::VpcLink
    Properties:
      Name: MyApiVpcLink
      Description: Allows data-api-gateway to access the VPC that my-api is on.
      TargetArns:
        - !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, myApiNetworkLoadBalancer]

  DataApi:
    DependsOn:
      - MyApiVpcLink
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentType}-data-api"
      StageName: !Ref EnvironmentType
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        security:
          - ApiKey: []
        info:
          title: !Sub "${EnvironmentType}-data-api"
        paths:
          /sfdc/v1/my-api/{proxy+}:
            x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
              produces:
                - application/json
              parameters:
                - in: path
                  name: proxy
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: string
                - in: header
                  name: x-api-auth
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: string
              security:
                - SfdcAuthorizer: []
                  ApiKey: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
              x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
                ACCESS_DENIED:
                  statusCode: 403
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: '{\n\"message\": \"Access Denied\"}'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: ANY
                type: http_proxy
                connectionType: VPC_LINK
                connectionId: !Ref MyApiVpcLink
                passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
                uri: !If [UseProdCondition, 'http://myapp.production.aws-int.myorg.io/{proxy}',!Sub 'http://${EnvironmentType}-myapp.staging.aws-int.myorg.io/{proxy}']
                requestParameters:
                  integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
                  # -------------------- this breaks it once added -------------------
                  integration.request.header.x-api-auth: "$context.authorizer.x-api-auth"
                  # ------------------------------------------------------------------
        definitions:
          Empty:
            type: object
          Error:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
        securityDefinitions:
          SfdcAuthorizer:
            type: 'apiKey'
            name: 'Authorization'
            in: 'header'
            x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: 'custom'
            x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
              authorizerUri: !Join ['', [!Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/', !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, sfdcAuthLambda], '/invocations']]
              authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, sfdcAuthTimeout]
              type: 'token'
          ApiKey:
            type: apiKey
            name: x-api-key
            in: header
```

Comment: I referred to this documentation in pulling the return from Lambda Authorizer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html

Answer (score 3):

Well... after getting nowhere with following the documentation, I went rogue and removed the "$" from "integration.request.header.x-api-auth"... AND THAT WORKED. Not sure how I feel about this.

Here is the complete working YAML file. I'm posting it here in case it should help someone else who is trying to set up a gateway which takes PROXY path and expects a return from a Lambda authorizer.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Data API pipeline initial Cloudformation template

Mappings:
  EnvironmentMapping:
    alpha:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: XYZ
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
    beta:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: XYZ
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
    prod:
      certificationArn: ""
      carfaxIpWhitelistRuleId: ""
      hostedZoneId: ABC
      authLambda: ""
      sfdcAuthLambda: ""
      myApiNetworkLoadBalancer: ""
      sfdcAuthTimeout: 1
Parameters:
  EnvironmentType:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedValues:
      - alpha
      - beta
      - prod

Conditions:
  UseProdCondition: !Equals [!Ref EnvironmentType, prod]

Resources:
  MyApiVpcLink:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::VpcLink
    Properties:
      Name: MYApiVpcLink
      Description: Allows data-api-gateway to access the VPC that feature-api is on.
      TargetArns:
        - !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, myApiNetworkLoadBalancer]

  DataApi:
    DependsOn:
      - MyApiVpcLink
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentType}-data-api"
      StageName: !Ref EnvironmentType
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        security:
          - ApiKey: []
        info:
          title: !Sub "${EnvironmentType}-data-api"
        paths:
          /sfdc/v1/my-api/{proxy+}:
            x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
              produces:
                - application/json
              parameters:
                - in: path
                  name: proxy
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: string
                - in: header
                  name: x-api-auth
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: string
              security:
                - SfdcAuthorizer: []
                  ApiKey: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
              x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
                ACCESS_DENIED:
                  statusCode: 403
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: '{\n\"message\": \"Access Denied\"}'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: ANY
                type: http_proxy
                connectionType: VPC_LINK
                connectionId: !Ref MyApiVpcLink
                passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
                uri: !If [UseProdCondition, 'http://myapp.production.aws-int.myorg.io/{proxy}',!Sub 'http://${EnvironmentType}-myapp.staging.aws-int.myorg.io/{proxy}']
                requestParameters:
                  integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
                  integration.request.header.x-api-auth: "context.authorizer.x-api-auth"
        definitions:
          Empty:
            type: object
          Error:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
        securityDefinitions:
          SfdcAuthorizer:
            type: 'apiKey'
            name: 'Authorization'
            in: 'header'
            x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: 'custom'
            x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
              authorizerUri: !Join ['', [!Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/', !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, sfdcAuthLambda], '/invocations']]
              authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: !FindInMap [EnvironmentMapping, !Ref EnvironmentType, sfdcAuthTimeout]
              type: 'token'
          ApiKey:
            type: apiKey
            name: x-api-key
            in: header
```

Comment: Hey man, maybe you can help me. I have a lot of experience with Cloud Formation. But this APIs templates, OpenAPI syntax, and these keys like "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" really confuse me. For example, what is this for "x-amazon-apigateway-integration"?

Comment: Hi @Perimosh, I am definitely no expert, but I think x-amazon-apigateway-integration is Amazon's way of working with the OpenAPI project. OpenAPI offers the ability to Dynamically generates parts of the Cloudformation file. For example, the "/{proxy+}" in the configuration says the path can be anything. And the "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method" generates the YAML to allow all HTTP methods.